# Get sql to return correct post

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to get a sql query to return a post in my DB by its ID.

My table looks like this:

id|img|desc|date

And now i want to return a single post depending in the id that gets passed.
Im using PDO. And to return all posts i do like this:

```
function getUser($id) {
    echo $id; //i want to get the post that has this id.
}

function getProjects() {
    $sql = "select * FROM projects";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($users);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a **where** clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `WHERE` clause.

```
$sql = "select * FROM projects WHERE id = " . $whateveridyouwant;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a *SQL-Statement* with a **WHERE**-Clause like the following:

```
 $sql = "select * FROM projects where id=$id";
```

---

In the context of your project this could look like

```
getProjects($id);

function getProjects($id) {
    $sql = "select * FROM projects where id=$id";
    /* rest of your code */
}
```

Comment: You might want to expand this question with a little more context - as it is, it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProjects($id) { // you should pass the ID you want
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id =". $id;
   // rest of the code...
```

You just forgot the WHERE clause. I cant remember if this is the right syntax, but for sure is something like this. Try it.